# How to find the closest value to x in y dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, x and y, both of which represent items and their respective locations (which are represented as integers). Dataframe x responds to Genes and their locations; dataframe y responds to Enhancers and their locations. For every Gene in dataframe x, I want to find the Enhancer in y whose location is closest. Here are the first five rows of both dataframes:

```
Gene:           | Location:                            
----------------------------------                    
CORT            | 10450031             
LOC107985174    | 110639954
LOC105369199    | 120963648
CD1D            | 158178030
EPHA2           | 16124337


         Enhancer:                  |   Location:
-----------------------------------------------------
genic|NC_000001.11:180541-181713    |   180541
genic|NC_000001.11:819650-823755    |   819650   
genic|NC_000001.11:1290023-1294341  |   1290023
genic|NC_000001.11:2072541-2076498  |   2072541
genic|NC_000001.11:2132164-2134268  |   2132164
```

I have been using `which.min()` like so: `Enhancers[which.min(abs(x-Enhancers$location)),]` where `x` corresponds to the given gene's location, which does appear to work, but it requires manually inputing the location of each individual gene. I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this for all the genes at once. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could expand a grid with both data sets, group by Gene and select the row with the minimum absolute difference in location for each Gene.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

set.seed(2105)

x <- data.frame(Gene = letters[1:5], Location = 1:5)
y <- data.frame(Enhancer = letters[6:10], Location_enh = 5*runif(5))

x
#>   Gene Location
#> 1    a        1
#> 2    b        2
#> 3    c        3
#> 4    d        4
#> 5    e        5
y
#>   Enhancer Location_enh
#> 1        f    1.2275958
#> 2        g    2.2874741
#> 3        h    4.2954764
#> 4        i    4.2017862
#> 5        j    0.9555975

expand_grid(x, y) %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  slice_min(abs(Location - Location_enh)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Gene  Location Enhancer Location_enh
#>   <chr>    <int> <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 a            1 j               0.956
#> 2 b            2 g               2.29 
#> 3 c            3 g               2.29 
#> 4 d            4 i               4.20 
#> 5 e            5 h               4.30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Looks like genetic data. If you're already using Bioconductor packages, then [Biobase](https://bioconductor.org/packages/Biobase)`::matchpt()` will do the trick quickly and efficiently (and in multiple dimensions).

Using the simple example from @seb09, we have

```
set.seed(2105)
x <- data.frame(Gene = letters[1:5], Location = 1:5)
y <- data.frame(Enhancer = letters[6:10], Location_enh = 5*runif(5))
index <- matchpt(x$Location, y$Location_enh)$index
index
## [1] 5 2 2 4 3
```

and (a little extra work to clean up some funky row names from `cbind()`)

```
result <- cbind(x, y[index,,drop = FALSE])
rownames(result) <- NULL
result
##   Gene Location Enhancer Location_enh
## 1    a        1        j    0.9555975
## 2    b        2        g    2.2874741
## 3    c        3        g    2.2874741
## 4    d        4        i    4.2017862
## 5    e        5        h    4.2954764
```

Using @nisetama's benchmark we have

```
l1 = 1e3
l2 = 2e3
x = data.frame(
    gene = paste0(letters,1:l1),
    Location = round(runif(l1)*1e8)
)
y = data.frame(
    enhancer = paste0(letters,1:l2),
    Location_enh = round(runif(l2)*1e8)
)

identical(
    sapply(x[,2],\(v)which.min(abs(v-y[,2]))),
    matchpt(x$Location, y$Location_enh)$index
)
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(
    sapply = sapply(x[,2],\(v)which.min(abs(v-y[,2]))),
    matchpt = matchpt(x$Location, y$Location_enh)
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##   sapply 32.21390 33.19321 35.21607 33.35805 39.23552 41.05420   100
##  matchpt 10.91162 10.93015 11.00443 11.01078 11.06492 11.19677   100
```

Answer (score 1):

This data doesn't show enough similarity to be interesting, but I think this method will work for what you need:

```r
apply(abs(outer(df1$Location, df2$Location, `-`)), 1, which.min)
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5
```

This is saying that `df1$Location`s are all closest to the 5th value of `df2$Location`.

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("CORT", "LOC107985174", "LOC105369199", "CD1D", "EPHA2"), Location = c(10450031, 110639954, 120963648, 158178030, 16124337)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
df2 <- structure(list(Enhancer = c("NC_000001.11:180541-181713", "NC_000001.11:819650-823755", "NC_000001.11:1290023-1294341", "NC_000001.11:2072541-2076498", "NC_000001.11:2132164-2134268"), Location = c(180541, 819650, 1290023, 2072541, 2132164)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In my benchmark it was faster to just use `sapply(df1$Location,\(v)which.min(abs(df2$Location-v)))` instead of `outer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distance_join` set of functions from `fuzzyjoin` R package to join 2 tables by distance. You can provide `max_dist` argument to show NA if there is no data within the specified range.

For this demo I've used the test data from @seb09's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73365441/163080).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

set.seed(2105)

x <- data.frame(Gene = letters[1:5], Location = 1:5)
y <- data.frame(Enhancer = letters[6:10], Location_enh = 5*runif(5))

distance_left_join(x, y, by = c("Location" = "Location_enh"), max_dist = 1)
#>   Gene Location Enhancer Location_enh
#> 1    a        1        f    1.2275958
#> 2    a        1        j    0.9555975
#> 3    b        2        f    1.2275958
#> 4    b        2        g    2.2874741
#> 5    c        3        g    2.2874741
#> 6    d        4        h    4.2954764
#> 7    d        4        i    4.2017862
#> 8    e        5        h    4.2954764
#> 9    e        5        i    4.2017862
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you need to select a single enhancer per gene with closest distance:

```
distance_left_join(x, y, by = c("Location" = "Location_enh"), max_dist = 1) %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  slice_min(abs(Location - Location_enh))
```

Comment: In the OP's case you need to add `max_dist=Inf`, because otherwise `fuzzyjoin::distance_left_join` returns NA for each row whose closest neighbor has a distance over 1.

Comment: Good comment. In general, yes. But in this particular case enhancer cannot be too far from the gene it potentially regulates. It's better to define the limit.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a vector of the matches:

```
l1=1e3;l2=2e3
x=data.frame(Gene=paste0(letters,1:l1),Location=round(runif(l1)*1e8))
y=data.frame(Enhancer=paste0(letters,1:l2),Location_enh=round(runif(l2)*1e8))

y[,1][sapply(x[,2],\(v)which.min(abs(y[,2]-v)))]
```

This adds the matches as a new column:

```
cbind(x,min=y[,1][sapply(x[,2],\(v)which.min(abs(y[,2]-v)))])
```

Benchmark (edit: added `Biobase::matchpt` and an Rcpp option):

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector xclosest(NumericVector x,NumericVector y){
  int l1=x.length(),l2=y.length();
  NumericVector out(l1);
  for(int i=0;i<l1;i++){
    double min=abs(x[i]-y[0]);
    int minind=0;
    for(int j=1;j<l2;j++)if(abs(x[i]-y[j])<min){min=abs(x[i]-y[j]);minind=j;}
    out[i]=minind;
  }
  return out;
}")

l1=1e3;l2=2e3
x=data.frame(Gene=paste0(letters,1:l1),Location=round(runif(l1)*1e8))
y=data.frame(Enhancer=paste0(letters,1:l2),Location_enh=round(runif(l2)*1e8))

microbenchmark(times=10,
  sapply=sapply(x[,2],\(v)which.min(abs(v-y[,2]))),
  outer_with_apply=apply(abs(outer(x[,2],y[,2],`-`)),2,which.min),
  outer_with_rowMins=Rfast::rowMins(abs(outer(x[,2],y[,2],`-`))),
  tidyverse=expand_grid(x,y)%>%group_by(Gene)%>%slice_min(abs(Location-Location_enh))%>%ungroup(),
  distance_left_join=fuzzyjoin::distance_left_join(x,y,by=c("Location"="Location_enh"),max_dist=Inf),
  matchpt=matchpt(x$Location,y$Location_enh),
  xclosest_cpp=xclosest(x$Location,y$Location_enh)
)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
               expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval
             sapply    15.208904    15.293551    17.201444    15.981592    17.890364    22.120634    10
   outer_with_apply    34.881275    57.996456    55.564075    59.004213    59.365812    66.721156    10
 outer_with_rowMins    18.468577    18.702030    40.420237    29.428359    35.666042   162.829603    10
          tidyverse   555.895686   572.182184   860.772970   739.746102  1111.044602  1525.000602    10
 distance_left_join 11138.266735 12269.768424 13375.626662 13433.652742 14787.006978 15079.786089    10
            matchpt     5.088065     5.103749     5.211020     5.229232     5.287886     5.399156    10
       xclosest_cpp     2.199385     2.204919     2.341288     2.209788     2.220550     3.517052    10
```